# The user-profile.tpl.php file won´t be recognized in my Drupal 7 installation

Tags: 7, users, theming

I´ve created a file user-profile.tpl.php in a Drupal 7 installation. I´ve updated the site from Drupal 6.
I have old core profile fields and I´ve installed the new profile2 module.

I´ve inserted that user-profile file into my theme folder and flushed cache.
I want the profile to show all the core profile fields and the new profile 2 fields.

The thing is that it won´t show any field at all. It just shows the user picture.

After a lot of trying and error, I´ve tried deleting all the content inside user-profile.tpl.php file, and adding into it just "hello world". It won´t be printed out. And the profile picture is still there.

**So, how do I get the file to be recognized? Should I set something at my template.tpl.php file?**

Thanks for your help!!

Rosamunda

Comment: Any time you add a new template file you need to clear Drupal's cache...have you done that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I´ve flushed cache, several times.

Comment: May you show the code you are using in your user-profile.tpl.php file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I´ve deleted all the content inside user-profile.tpl.php file, and adding into it just the text "hello world". It won´t be printed out. And the profile picture is still there.

Comment: try disabling Display Suite Module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding your content in the user profile template [preprocess](http://drupal.org/node/223430) function instead.

e.g, in template.php:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_user_profile
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
  // Fetch relevant user account
  $account = $variables['elements']['#account'];
  // Add content to user profile render array
  $variables['user_profile'][] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup', 
    '#markup' => 'Hello world'
  );
}
```

After adding a new preprocess function, clear theme registry cache, e.g at `Admin > Performance > Clear all caches`

Comment: Thanks for your reply David! I´ve tried that (and flushed cache after it), and it still won´t show up. it´s pretty weird.

Answer (score 1):

After adding content to user profile template preprocess function,to display it on user profile page, you need to render that content. I recently had the same issue. So I created the preprocess function inside my theme's **template.php** file as suggested by **David Thomas** and created a **user-profile.tpl.php** file (just copy the user-profile.tpl.php from User module) **inside my theme's template** folder and rendered whatever content I wanted to display. In your case it should be something like:

```
print render($user_profile['content_name']);
```

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

It must be possible to print anything when you have properly reckognized user-profile.tpl.php.

In my case it works out of the box. If i delete content of whole file, and just type "test" in it, page shows only "test".

**Try this**: Make sure that your user-profile.tpl.php is in **/templates** sub directory, not in root of your template folder, otherwise it won't work!